# Nifi Unable to convert CSV to Excel using POI API

Tags: java, groovy, apache-poi, apache-nifi, groovy-grape

I want to convert csv flowfile content into XLS file usin groovy script + POI API

I m using ivy to grab POI dependencies and it seems work well.

please find more details below:

This is my Nifi flow:

[image]

This is my script

```
@Grapes(@Grab(group='org.apache.poi', module='poi-ooxml', version='3.9'))
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.extractor.*
import java.nio.charset.*
import java.io.*
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def flowFile = session.get()
def date = new Date()

if(!flowFile) return

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
try {
    
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream,);
Sheet mySheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);


def record = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
outputStream.write(record.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

wb.close();

} catch(e) {
 log.error("Error during processing", e)
 session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
}
} as StreamCallback)


def filename = flowFile.getAttribute('filename')+'.xlsx'
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'filename', filename) 

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

I get this error
[image]

Any idea about this error ?

Edit:
I changed my script and still had the same error:

```
@Grapes(@Grab(group='org.apache.poi', module='poi-ooxml', version='3.9'))
import com.opencsv.CSVReader
@Grapes(@Grab(group='com.opencsv', module='opencsv', version='4.2'))
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.extractor.*
import java.nio.charset.*
import java.io.*
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def flowFile = session.get()
def date = new Date()

if(!flowFile) return

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
try {
def nextLine = ''
reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilePath), FILE_DELIMITER);

  Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream,);
 Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Feuille");

// workBook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
//sheet = (SXSSFSheet) workBook.createSheet('Sheet');

int rowNum = 0;
while((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
Row currentRow = sheet1.createRow(rowNum++);
for(int i=0; i < nextLine.length; i++) {
if(NumberUtils.isDigits(nextLine[i])) {
currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(nextLine[i]));
} else if (NumberUtils.isNumber(nextLine[i])) {
currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(nextLine[i]));
} else {
currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(nextLine[i]);
}
}
}

fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(generatedXlsFilePath.trim());
wb.write(fileOutputStream);

wb.close();
fileOutputStream.close();
reader.close();
outputStream.close();

} catch(e) {
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
}
} as StreamCallback)

def filename = flowFile.getAttribute('filename')+'.xlsx'
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'filename', filename)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: Does your code work outside of NiFi? As I can't see anything reading a CSV, can't see anything writing meaningful stuff to rows and cells in Apache POI, I'm guessing not... You'll need to fix your code to work standalone first!

Comment: You are creating WorkbookFactory from input stream but you are saying that input contains csv file. So, poi saying that can't read input stream because it's not ole2 or ooxml...

Comment: @daggett I want to convert csv content into xls format, can you help with the script please?